# conflicting implementations

Tags: rust

Создал структуру Vector2:

```
struct Vector2<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T
}
```

Хочу сделать так, чтобы объекты структуры можно было легко преобразовывать между собой, например:

```
let v1 = Vector2::<u8> { x: 0, y: 0 };
let v2 = Vector2::<u16>::from(v1);
```

Пытался реализовать это так:

```
impl<T1, T2> From<Vector2<T1>> for Vector2<T2>
    where T2: From<T1> {
    fn from(vector: Vector2<T1>) -> Self {
        Self {
            x: T2::from(vector.x),
            y: T2::from(vector.y)
        }
    }
}
```

Но компилятор выдает ошибку:

> ```
> error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<Vector2<_>>` for type `Vector2<_>`:
>   --> src/main.rs:7:1
>    |
> 7  | / impl<T1, T2> From<Vector2<T1>> for Vector2<T2>
> 8  | |     where T2: From<T1> {
> 9  | |     fn from(vector: Vector2<T1>) -> Self {
> 10 | |         Self {
> ...  |
> 14 | |     }
> 15 | | }
>    | |_^
>    |
>    = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
>            - impl<T> std::convert::From<T> for T;
> ```

И это понятно, ведь `From<T>` уже реализуется для `T`, а тут, помимо других типов, я пытаюсь повторно реализовать `From<T>` для `T`, но остается не ясно, как обойти эту проблему и сделать то, что я хочу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, делать такие вещи в Rust в обобщенном виде нельзя. Этот вопрос обсуждался, но [тема развития не получила](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1834).

Придется вручную написать имплементации для каждой пары типов, которые вы собираетесь использовать.

Можно немного упростить себе жизнь с помощью макросов:

```
macro_rules! impl_FromVector2{
    ($($T1:ty => $T2:ty),*) => {$(  
        impl From<Vector2<$T1>> for Vector2<$T2> {
            fn from(vector: Vector2<$T1>) -> Self {
                Self { x: vector.x.into(), y: vector.y.into() }
            }
        }
    )*}
}

impl_FromVector2!{u8 => u16, u8 => f32 }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b2f7f4deb9b57c69b00bdd78679f3f81&version=stable)